Difference between Partial Least Squares and Canonical Correlation Analysis
As far as I understand Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) and Partial Least Squares (PLS) are aiming to identify a set of projections in a space within which samples have maximum Correlation (in CCA) or Covariance (in PLS).
So in essence, in CCA we ignore the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix. This makes sense to me as (I guess) we do not care about the interrelationship between the identified projections. In fact, we do not want them to be correlated (otherwise they would be identical), so I guess we would like the off-diagonals to be zero.
My questions are:

Why do we want to maximize the off-diagonals in PLS?
If we maximize the covariance in PLS (so we end up with correlated projections), then wouldnt we end up with duplicated (non-informative) projections?
Wikipedia seems to suggest that the optimization is pairwise. But then if thats the case, we end up with CCA, wouldnt we?

